# standardsetcontroller getrecords() immutable list

Tags: apex, visualforce

In here [Getrecords](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getRecords.htm)
its says regarding getrecords method of standardsetcontroller as

> Returns the list of sObjects in the current page set. This list is
> immutable, i.e. you can't call clear() on it.

but i have this page

```
<apex:page controller="controller1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlocktable value="{!listbook}" var="b">
<apex:column value="{!b.name}"/>
</apex:pageBlocktable>
<apex:pageblockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton action="{!deleteit}"  value="Delete"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and controller

```
public class controller1 {
private apexpages.standardsetcontroller sc;
public list<book__C> booklist{get;set;}
public controller1()
{
sc = new apexpages.standardsetcontroller([select name from book__c]);
booklist = new list<book__C>();
booklist = (list<book__c>)sc.getrecords();
}
public void deleteit()
{
booklist[0].clear();
booklist[1].clear();
//booklist.clear(); //this does give exception
}
}
```

if i call booklist.clear() it does give an exception.

Now as seen above i can call clear on individual items in list and it doesnt give any exception.data gets removed from table.So what does it really mean by
saying list is immutable?

Comment: Semantics? You indeed can clear values of the individual records in the list, but you cannot clear the list itself. You still have a list with 2 items in it.

Comment: ok..i get the reason..so what exactly is getting cleared when we say for eg: any list of sobject ,and list[0].clear..I thought in memory we have a list of sobject pointers (some like ,{000X12abc,1240XXX}  which points to sobject records)and when we say clear that gets cleared?

Comment: If you do it in the dev console, the sObject gets cleared of all values. Per the sObject Methods: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm you are executing clear() on the sObject at index x and not the list itself. So technically you are not modifying the list.....Curious as the the reason behind it though

Comment: every primitive type integer, string, double are immutable once constructed with a value, they can never be changed. Any operation just creates a new Object using the value as base, so it seems they are passed by value, but its memory reference always.(Abhinav Gupta) via: comment on https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html